# Adding a table with picture to outlook template using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to copy a table that has a picture on the left cell and a set of names in the right cell to an Outlook Template. I tried the Ron de Bruin method of RangetoHTML method, but the picture did not get pastes and the names were not wrapped within the cell. So, I tried to paste it as a picture. But it is deleting the content of the template and pasting as a new message.

```
Dim OL As Outlook.Application, OLmail As Outlook.MailItem, rng As Range, p As Picture, strbody As String, wordDoc As Object

Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OLmail = OL.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\bhraman\Desktop\VBA practise\Add_picture_table_and_send_mail.msg")
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("f7:k7")
rng.Copy
Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
p.Cut

With OLmail
    .To = "bhraman@deloitte.com"
    .Subject = "Test"

    Set wordDoc = OLmail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    wordDoc.Range.Paste
    '.HTMLBody = Replace(OLmail.HTMLBody, "Trw", wordDoc.Range.Paste)
    '.display
    strbody = "Congratulations on your service anniversary with the team! We look forward to many more successful years with you!.<br><br>"
    '.HTMLBody = Replace(OLmail.HTMLBody, "TRW", wordDoc.Range.Paste)
    .HTMLBody = Replace(OLmail.HTMLBody, "Trw", strbody & "<br><br>" & p & "Regards,<br>Talent")
    '.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Talent"
    .display
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is **copypicture** not **copy**.

```
    Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OLmail = OL.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\bhraman\Desktop\VBA practise\Add_picture_table_and_send_mail.msg")
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("f7:k7")
    'Rng.Copy
    Rng.CopyPicture
    'Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
   ' p.Cut
    
    With OLmail
        .To = "bhraman@deloitte.com"
        .Subject = "Test"
    
        Set wordDoc = OLmail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        wordDoc.Range.Paste
        '.HTMLBody = Replace(OLmail.HTMLBody, "Trw", wordDoc.Range.Paste)
        '.display
        strbody = "Congratulations on your service anniversary with the team! We look forward to many more successful years with you!.<br><br>"
        '.HTMLBody = Replace(OLmail.HTMLBody, "TRW", wordDoc.Range.Paste)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(OLmail.HTMLBody, "Trw", strbody & "<br><br>" & p & "Regards,<br>Talent")
        '.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Talent"
        .display
```

Comment: I tried that, with wordDoc.range.paste, the copied range is getting pasted on the excel instead of replacing it in the html. Any thoughts?